# Bad ELF interpreter, when using java in fedora

Tags: java, linux, fedora

I'm very green in Linux. I installed jdk1.7 downloaded from oracle(which is a rpm file) and changed the .bash_profile to add the JAVAHOME and CLASSPATH like this:

> ```
> JAVAHOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.006 export JAVA_HOME
>
> PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH export PATH
>
> CLASSPATH=.:$JAVAHOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVAHOME/lib/tools.jar export CLASSPATH
> ```

and i reboot. but when i try:

> ```
> java -version
> ```

the following will be displayed:

> ```
> bash: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_06/bin/java: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
> ```

then i tried :

> ```
> su -c 'yum install glibc.i686'
> ```

and will lead to:

> Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit   Resolving
>   Dependencies There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might
>   consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them. -->
>   Running transaction check ---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.15-51.fc17 will
>   be installed --> Processing Dependency:
>   libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH3.12.3) for package: glibc-2.15-51.fc17.i686
>   --> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so for package: glibc-2.15-51.fc17.i686 --> Running transaction check ---> Package
>   nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.13.5-1.fc17 will be installed --> Finished
>   Dependency Resolution Error: Protected multilib versions:
>   glibc-2.15-51.fc17.i686 != glibc-2.15-37.fc17.x8664 Error: Protected
>   multilib versions: nss-softokn-freebl-3.13.5-1.fc17.i686 !=
>   nss-softokn-freebl-3.13.4-2.fc17.x86_64

I just don't understand what's wrong with it?

Before I installed jdk1.7, I tried java -version and I will get some response like openJDK or something.

btw, when i installed the java, before 'complete', it showed alse bad ELF interpreter error and i ignored them.

i would appreciate it if any of you can provide a solution. and forgive my poor English.

Comment: Any particular reason to use the Oracle version? I find the OpenJDK bundled with Fedora to be perfectly adequate.

Comment: @artbristol Sadly, it's not working well for all applications. I've run into at least two client applications that do not work properly with OpenJDK. One might claim that it's sloppy client development and not a problem with OpenJDK but, still, the end result is that installing the Oracle JDK solves the problem.

Comment: If those are not typos in your posting, you are using JAVAHOME in some places and JAVA_HOME in others which might lead to mixing libraries between OpenJDK and the Oracle JDK. Another thing to check is that you have the right type of binary. Ex: installing a 64-bit binary on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: yes, maybe it is the JAVA_HOME that arouse the problem